# How to make an app window extend vertically between two monitors fully with separate Spaces off?

Tags: display, window-manager, mission-control

I use a monitor arrangement that incorporates two monitors in a vertical alignment, eg, this is a segment from `System Preferences → Displays` that shows how these two monitors are arranged:
[image: monitor arrangement]

(NOTE: I operate with `System Preferences → Mission Control → Displays have separate Spaces: OFF` which facilitates this style of necessary workflow.
[image: separate spaces off]

)

I frequently find myself needing to stretch an application vertically between these two monitors for various reasons, however Apple seems to have a feature (bug) that when I attempt to stretch out such a window as far as possible vertically between the two screens it will snap onto the screen that has the majority of the app placement at when I release the resize cursor.

Presently I have to fiddle for an inordinate amount of time to try to get "enough" of the app on both displays in order to accomplish my goals, but it's really never satisfactory.

What is the feature / setting that controls this called?

I'd like to figure the name or feature that facilitates this so that I can either turn it off or report it to Apple since multi-monitor functionality seems to be getting back to a good priority after the multi-monitor support has been really refocused as a priority with the newer Apple Silicon systems.

Comment: Works here - not how I normally have them arranged, but tested OK. Can only test Mojave, none of the other Macs have 2 screens. Is the top screen set as primary? Do the screens match perfectly in Displays > Arrangement? If you're trying to map over a mis-matched area in there it will probably fight you - https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7ZWS.png

Comment: Running Monterey here. Well, I have 8 different monitors attached via Thunderbolt + USB adapter. The primary monitor is the "top" one in this mockup I extracted and the bottom one is my integrated laptop display. The top one is larger than the laptop display below.

Comment: We need to see how they line up in the Arrangement page, not physically. I suspect they're not lined up in a way that will work.

Comment: The above is exactly as you ask. None of the other monitors are at all involved in this situation and scenario. The above is from the arrangement page as I stated.

Comment: The above is an artist's impression of what you think it is. Why not just screenshot the Arrange page so we can all be sure?

Comment: @Tetsujin, no, this is not an artistic rendition - it simply has an "app" added as an overlay to convey position thereof. This is a screenshot of the Arrangement page sans the extraneous monitors, note: https://p153.p0.n0.cdn.getcloudapp.com/items/6quzEENo/08871e85-4977-43c6-bbb4-db37ee7dd1aa.jpg

Comment: Wow! I have no way of testing that kind of layout. It works with 2 displays. Perhaps try to reduce the issue to as simple a setup as will re-create the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I have the same thing with only two monitors as well. 

Comment: Sorry, not sure what to suggest then. I can't test Monterey as the only multi-screen Mac I have is still on Mojave.